# Solana Anchor installation trouble via powershell

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I’m trying to install Solana Anchor through Powershell, I’m greeted with this error, can’t seem to solve it, could you please help?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUGRO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> Visual C++ must be installed for successful compilation of program.

Please follow 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170
to install relevant vc++ version for yourself.